# repairing windows bootloader

Tags: windows-7

Hi i recently installed opensuse 11.3 dual boot with windows 7. Now i plan to remove opensuse from my comp and also tried removing it only to realise windows does not boot as grub loader is no longer existent. Now is there anyway i can get windows to boot. Unfortunately i dont have windows 7 installation dvd so i can be using fixmbr or its variants...
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

isos for recovery disks:
32 bit - http://www.mediafire.com/file/kdszp4wdvs3d2at/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_32bit_Recovery_Disc.iso
64 bit - http://www.mediafire.com/file/9k8zmsphhq41ogw/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_64bit_Recovery_Disc.iso

boot from media and select startup repair

Windows 7 recovery walkthrough: http://cybernetnews.com/windows-7-recovery-disc/

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD. It includes options to either restore the Master Boot Record from the backup or generate a new MBR

[This](http://www.arsgeek.com/2008/01/15/how-to-fix-your-windows-mbr-with-an-ubuntu-livecd/) site should walk you through it nicely.

Comment: he's coming back from suse not ubuntu...i'm not sure if suse backs up the mbr...just a thought.  generating a new one should work though

Comment: The link in the answer is broken and should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation doesn't sound so good.  Here are a few things I would try:

1. try an older version of windows, it's fixmbr may work for Windows 7
2. copy the boot sector off of a similarly configured system (that has the windows mbr), and write it to your current boot sector (using a livecd and dd, perhaps?)
3. borrow a copy of a windows 7 install disk
4. give your drive to someone else and ask them to unplug all of their drives and run fixmbr for you

Comment: vista might work out okay, xp should not. either way, i linked to some recovery disks